# List Find() StackOverflow Error

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, stack-overflow

I am getting a StackOverflow Error in this code:

**EDIT**

```
[XmlAttribute("ID")]
public string ID { get; set; }
```

**EDIT2**

```
 public ParameterEntity this[string szID]
    {
        get
        {
            //Finds the parameter entity with the ID passed in.
            return rParameters.Find(
                  delegate(ParameterEntity oParameterEntity)
                  {
                      return oParameterEntity.ID.Equals(szID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                  });
        }
    }
```

Can you guys please advise?

I might just have to use a simple manual looping.

Thanks
-Oliver

Comment: Does the getter of ParameterEntity.ID have any funky code in it?

Comment: Yep, 1-please provide the ID getter (seems the there is in fact two ID getter)

Comment: can you give some more details or larger snapshot of your code?

Comment: Instead of .ToLower() use: string.Equals(x.ID, ID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Comment: I have added the ID property to the mix.
Thanks Keith I will do.

@sevavladimirov the ID is not something that is heavily relied on and not a DBID or anything like that so I think that a string is sufficient in this case... the ID is actually more of a Key but its to late to change now.

Comment: And when does the first chunk of code is called ?

Comment: I have changed the ID as I saw that too, and am testing that now.

Comment: NB : The set property does nothing in fact what is the expected behaviour ?

Comment: I'm assuming the set is the same as 

set
{
 _localVar = value;
}

Comment: Oliver: no. the value isn't inserted to the list - you just play with the pointer.

Comment: If you have a member variable called "oCurrentEntity" too, the variable "oCurrentEntity"  inside the set property hide it. If not, the "oCurrentEntity" inside the set property is local to the set and can no longer be called so it's pointless.

Comment: LOL, thanks Duaner that is a pretty pointless setting

Comment: Just as an aside comment, you're using auto implementing properties so must be on C#3, so perhaps look at using lambdas rather than anonymous methods. It'll make your code more readable.

Comment: I have edited the code to represent what I have now

Comment: @Charlie, yes I am using C# 3 can you provide and example. I haven't worked with lamdas.

Comment: While you're at it, try linq. that's rParameters.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ID.Equals(szID));

Comment: Anyway do you still have the stackoverflow issue ? If so could you display the stack ?

Comment: @Oliver - are you sure this is the problem? Can we see a **stack trace** of your exception?

Comment: @Oliver Something like rParameters.Find(s=>s.ID.Equals(szID,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

Comment: Ok Guys!!! It looks like it may NOT be my code (although posting here has made me improve a few things).

The dev that is accessing my Collection seems to be the culprit as I have tried a normal for loop and I still get the error.

I think he may have some recursion that is not working.

Comment: Come to think of it, do we have stack traces for a stack-overflow exceptions? Isn't that too long?

Comment: @ Charlie: Lambdas... look awesome. I must look into them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was elsewhere.

Comment: A common problem with a stack overflow exception is not the drop that made the water in the glass spill over the edges, but all those drops before it that made the glass almost full. Typically you have a long stackframe with the actual recursion problem, and then an innocent looking method call that triggers the exception. The problem is not that method, but the recursive path before it.

Comment: Agreed, This was in an infrastructure class that was being called by another member of my team and he had a recursive method. So after much investigation it turned out to be a problem his side.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your ID property is trying to return itself, or set itself

Something like

```
private int _ID;

public int ID{
   get{return ID;}
   set{ID=value;}
}
```

Obviously it's probably not something that simple, but along those lines

(many edits ;P)